# Problem-Solving Essay

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I don't understand how to solve this problem. I guessed it's sort of a Law of Sines/Cosines Word Problem:

George was going fishing in his small fishing boat.  As he left the boat ramp to motor out into the lake, he noticed that two ropes had been strung from poles on opposite sides of the entrance to the lake. The poles were 6 ft and 10 ft tall.  The ropes went from the top of each pole to the bottom of the other pole. George quickly noticed that the highest point for getting under the ropes was where the two ropes crossed. If he kneeled down in the boat below the tallest part of the boat which is 3.5 ft high, will he make it underneath the ropes and be able to go fishing? How high is that point of intersection? There is no sagging in the ropes, and you do NOT need any other information to solve this problem. Show all your work and make sure to find the height of the point that the ropes intersect in ft. Draw a brief sketch, label the lengths, and describe in detail why you solved in the manner you solved.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro sorry. I removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Two ropes crossed]

The situation is as shown in the diagram above. $EF$ is a vertical line, thus parallel to $AB$ and $CD$, with a length of $h$. Also, $|BF| = x$ and $|FC| = y$.

You don't need to use the law of sines or the law of cosines but, instead, just use similar triangles. In particular, note that since $AB$ and $EF$ are parallel to each other, that $\angle CEF = \angle CAB$. Since they have an angle in common of $\angle ACB$, plus both $\angle EFC$ and $\angle ABC$ are right angles, then $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle EFC$ are similar to each other. You thus have

$$\frac{h}{y} = \frac{10}{x + y} \implies h = \frac{10y}{x + y} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Also, using basically the same arguments as above, you can show that $\triangle DCB$ is similar to $\triangle EFB$, so

$$\frac{h}{x} = \frac{6}{x + y} \implies h = \frac{6x}{x + y} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

From \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A} you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{10y}{x + y} & = \frac{6x}{x + y} \\
10y & = 6x \\
y & = \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)x
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Substituting this into \eqref{eq2A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h & = \frac{6x}{x + \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)x
} \\
& = \frac{6}{1 + \frac{3}{5}} \\
& = \frac{6}{\frac{8}{5}} \\
& = \frac{30}{8} \\
& = 3.75
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

As you can see, the point of intersection is $3.75$ ft. tall, giving $0.25$ ft. of clearance for the boat.

Comment: Another way to get this solution begins with the observation that triangles ABE and CDE are similar (with vertex A corresponding to C, not D).